# Copy file into all subdirectories that contains a file with certain name

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I am trying to copy a `features[30,55].R` script from my desktop into all the subdirectories that contain a file whose name is `DONE`.

I tried the following command:

```
find . -name "DONE"  -exec sh  'cp /Users/percyli/Desktop/features[30,55].R {}' \;
```

however, it gives you the following error:

```
sh: cp /Users/percyli/Desktop/features[30,55].R ./DONE: No such file or directory
sh: cp /Users/percyli/Desktop/features[30,55].R ./F3/F3-1/DONE: No such file or directory
```

where `./F3/F3-1` is one of the folders that contains the "DONE" file.

I also tried:

```
find . -name "DONE"  -exec cp /Users/percyli/Desktop/features[30,55].R {} \;
```

It does not spit out an error but nothing actually happens after I run this command.

What might be the problem here and how can I fix this?

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: `find . -name DONE -execdir cp /Users/percyli/Desktop/features\[30,55\].R . \;` as you can see the filename needs some escaping to avoid those "No such file or directory" errors.

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
f='/path/to/features[30,55].R'

find . -type f -name DONE \
    -exec sh -c 'echo cp "$1" "$(dirname "$2")"' sh "$f" {} ';'
```

This correctly calls `sh` with a script that copies the named file to the directory of the found `DONE` file.

Remove the `echo` once you are sure it's doing the correct thing.

Alternatively,

```
find . -type f -name DONE \
    -execdir cp "$f" . ';'
```

... if your `find` has `-execdir`.

---

Your issue was threefold:

1. The error comes from leaving `-c` out  from `sh -c`, which means `sh` was trying to execute a script called `cp /Users/perc...` (all as one single name). It did not find this file.
2. The subshell also has improper quoting of the filename. Since it contains filename globbing characters, it needs to be quoted.
3. Putting `{}` inside the script is potentially dangerous, or can at least have confusing consequence. See for example [Why does Solaris 10 find / -exec sh -c "echo {}" \; print "{}" instead of filenames?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271292/why-does-solaris-10-find-exec-sh-c-echo-print-instead-of-filena)

Your second try will overwrite the `DONE` files with the contents of the R script. Here too, you should quote the filename of the R script (this won't fix it though).