# Why does Solaris 10 find / -exec sh -c "echo {}" \; print "{}" instead of filenames?

Tags: find, solaris

I do not generally use Solaris,  but today I need to craft a find command to execute an operation on identified files using the shell.  I am finding that the `{}` characters are not getting substituted and cannot find an alternative.

For example:

```
 bash-3.2# find / -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;
```

This causes it to print `{}` for each file instead of the file name.

Comment: Try removing the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the man page and in the standard, `{}` must be in a separate argument.

`find / -exec sh -c 'echo $1' dummy '{}' \;`

works as expected.

Note that the parameter `dummy` is needed as the shell assigns the first argument after the command argument for `sh -c cmd` to become `$0` and the next parameter becomes `$1`.

Comment: And this is the link to the [said standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html): *If a `utility_name` or `argument` string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether `find` replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.*  It seems GNU `find` replaces "{}" characters that are combined with other characters, Solaris `find` does not.

Comment: `gfind` does not behave orthogonal, `gfind . -exec echo "aaa {}" \;` works as expected, but `gfind . -exec echo "aaa {}" +` behaves as if `gfind . -exec echo "{}" +` was called.

Comment: Well, IEEE 1003.1 doesn't mandate that an implementation's definition must be consistent...

Comment: I would clarify, for the inexperienced reader seeking for knowledge, that `dummy` is required by `sh`, and not by `find`, since `sh -c` takes one mandatory argument, the command string here represented by `'echo $1'`, and optionally other arguments, where the first, `dummy` in this case, is available in the command as `$0`, and the following ones, in this case only `'{}'` (which is not required to be quoted, as far as I can say), as `$1`, `$2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

The only standard way to use `find -exec …` is to pass `{}` as a separate argument. The behavior when an argument contains `{}` is not standardized. It seems that you're used to the GNU behavior where `{}` is substituted in a substring. The `find` command on Solaris only substitutes `{}` when an argument consists only of `{}`.

The GNU behavior is not particularly useful, and sometimes annoying, because substituting a file name inside an argument is brittle. Unless you have known constraints on the file names, there's no way to know where a file name starts and ends. For example, with GNU find, `find / -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;` does *not* print the file names in general. It only prints the file names when they don't contain any shell special character. If you run it in a directory containing a file called `;rm -r ~`, say goodbye to your files.

The reliable (and portable) way to call a shell from `find -exec` is to pass the file names as an argument to the shell.

```
find … -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

In most cases you can pass arguments in batches and iterate over the arguments in the shell. It's somewhat faster. Note that the very first argument after the shell code is `$0` which is not includes in `"$@"`.

```
find … -exec sh -c 'for x; do echo "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

See also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)